# mac screen goes sleep mode even I set never sleep

Tags: macos, mac

I want my mac screen never dim, never sleep, never turn off.

below is my power setting

[image]

[image]

Problem: my mac goes log out and goes screen saver mode if it idles for 15 minutes.

Comment: pure guess... check what you have set in Screen Saver; time & 'image'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like your Mac will indeed never go to sleep, but the Screen Saver is set to activate after 15 minutes.

You can disable the screen saver by opening the Desktop & Screen Saver preference pane in System Preferences then selecting Never in the drop down box in the bottom left corner of the window.

[image]